# Ownership of conversion between static class and non static class

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design

I have a static class that performs xml serialization. Is it better for the static class to be responsible/implement for converting objects of type `foo` to their proper xml representation or to have `foo` implement its own `foo.ToXml()` method? The conversion just transfers information regarding `foo` into a data class with correct `XmlAttribute` and `XmlElement` properties.

Essentially:

```cs
var fooData = XmlClass.Convert(foo)
```

or

```cs
var fooData = foo.ToXml()
```

Comment: The answer to this question will depend greatly on how "standard" your XML representation is with respect to the `Foo` class. If everything translates one-to-one, then a separate class that can introspect `Foo` is more than sufficient. Otherwise, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# supports reflection, so you can [write a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257397/102937) to take advantage using introspection.  You would use `XmlClass.Convert` to convert `foo` (or any class).

In more general terms (and not specific to C#), if you are using a language that does not support reflection you should have `foo` do the conversion.  This is because `foo` knows the details of what a `foo` is; `XmlClass` does not, nor should it.  `foo` should implement a `ToXml` method to convert its data to an XML string.  It won't do this in isolation, and can (should) call helper methods in `XmlClass` to convert standard data types (like `Int` and `String`) to XML.  Having a `ToXml` method is also helpful because the XML conversion code is in the class, and any future changes to the class are less likely to miss updating the XML conversion code.

If you have `XmlClass` to the conversion, then `XmlClass` needs to know the details of `foo`.  This will cause a coupling between the two classes that does not need to exist, and increase the likelihood of bugs when changes are made to `foo` and the XML conversion code is not updated.  This would also violate the idea of [Separation of Concerns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32581/how-do-you-explain-separation-of-concerns-to-others).

Answer (score 0):

C# supports extension methods. So you can effectively employ both solutions together; no need to choose:

```
static class XmlConverters
{
    static Xml ToXml(this Foo foo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then use it as `var fooData = foo.ToXml()`.